# Auto-create unique ID from Name entered by user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

In Visual studio 2008, In web application(C#), In Supplier master web form, when I add new Vendor name like "Mac'D", I want its unique ID like (M001) to be created. this ID will generate from first Initial of name as 'M' along with 001, if there are another Vendor having first Initial 'M', then it go on next ID which (M002) and so on, if another vendor having different name like "KFC", then it will be like (K001).

Is it possible? If yes... then please help me in this..

Comment: Auto Incremented Column With VARCHAR       http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/auto-incremented-column-with-varchar-and-nvarchar-data-type/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code so that I can guide you.

Comment: Stpe 1: Provide how the data is saved in the database, before we can give any advise.

Comment: Safest way would be to use sequences, you could consider creating a sequence per letter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into SupplierMaster values('" + Convert.ToString(txtVendorID.Text) + "','" + null + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtVendorName.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtAddress.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtMobNo.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtMailId.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtCtcnPrsnNm.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtContactNo.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtVatTin.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToString(txtCstTin.Text) + "')", con);
       }  this is how record insert into a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SP_VENDORCODE
    @IN INT,
    @DATE DATETIME,
    @NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ADD1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @MOB NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @EMAIL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CONTACTPERSON NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @MOB1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @VAT NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CST NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @NEWID NVARCHAR(5);
    DECLARE @PREFIX NVARCHAR(1);
    SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NAME, 1, 1))
 SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,N.OID + 1))) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,N.OID + 1)) FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS null then 0 else MAX(T.TID) end as OID FROM (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(Code, 1, 1) as PRE_FIX,SUBSTRING(Code, 2, LEN(Code)) as TID FROM SupplierMaster
  ) AS T WHERE T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX
 ) AS N
INSERT INTO SupplierMaster VALUES(@IN,@NEWID,@DATE,@NAME,@ADD1,@MOB,@EMAIL,@CONTACTPERSON,@MOB1,@VAT,@CST)
END`